# Associations for Survey in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I need to conduct surveys for companies and maintain Results

To do that i created models like

```
Company  has_many :surveys
Survey   has_many :categories
Category  has_many :questions
Question  has_one  :answer
```

The Problem is for each survey i have same questions but company has different answers.

To resolve that

i rechained the relations like

```
Category has_many :answers, through: :questions
Company  has_many :answers, through: :surveys
Survey   has_many :answers, through: :categories
```

But i thought it is very complex relation model.
Anybody help me to build it simple